Capture KeyboardInterrupt in context manager when OpenMPI run is manually terminated
I am running code in parallel using mpi4py. I've noticed that if I run the code and perform a keyboard interrupt, my context manager __exit__ will run if I run the code as python file.py but will not when run as mpirun -np 1 file.py (this is only one process, but it produces the same as if I run the code with more processes).
How do I get the terminated MPI run to cause the code to exit like a normal python process and enter the context manager's __exit__ process?
Minimal reproducible example:
from mpi4py import MPI

def f(i):
    # raise KeyboardInterrupt()
    return i**0.5
    
class ContextManager():
    def __init__(self,):
        return
    
    def __enter__(self,):
        return self
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
        rank = comm.Get_rank()
        size = comm.Get_size()
        
        print("Exiting.")
        
        if rank == 0:
            print(rank, size)
            print(exc_type)
            print(exc_value)
            print(traceback)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ContextManager():
        for i in range(1_000_000):
            print(f(i))

If I uncomment the interrupt, whether the code is run via python file.py or mpirun -np 1 file.py, the context manager __exit__ is run and the printouts are displayed.
If I run the code as shown above (the interrupt is commented) and hit ctrl+C in the middle of the run, then:

if I ran the code as python file.py, __exit__ is entered and the printouts are displayed
if I ran the code as mpirun -np 1 python file.py, the code simply terminates and never enters __exit__ (i.e., there are no printouts).

Versions:
python: 3.10.14
mpirun: 4.1.4
mpi4py: 3.1.6
Ubuntu: 22.04.4 LTS


Edit: Following the answers in this question, the interrupt is still not captured.
from mpi4py import MPI
import signal

def sigterm_handler(signum, frame):
    print("Here")
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)


def f(i):
    # raise KeyboardInterrupt()
    return i**0.5
    
class ContextManager():
    def __init__(self,):
        return
    
    def __enter__(self,):        
        return self
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):   
        comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
        rank = comm.Get_rank()
        size = comm.Get_size()
        
        print("Exiting.")
        
        if rank == 0:
            print(rank, size)
            print(exc_type)
            print(exc_value)
            print(traceback)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ContextManager():
        for i in range(1_000_000):
            print(f(i))


What is stopping you from just running it without mpirun using just python? You can do multiprocessing with varying numbers of processes really easily in core python.

Because my real code is run on a supercomputer and I am using MPI to parallelize the code across many CPUs on the machine.

I would have thought that whatever OS you have on the supercomputer would treat many CPUs as just tonnes of cores, but I’m clearly wrong.

I think you probably need to put the whole for loop inside a try/except block.
if __name__ == "__main__":
   with ContextManager():
        try:
            for i in range(1_000_000):
                print(f(i))
        except KeyboardInterrupt: pass

I think it is because using some implementations of Python, KeyboardInterrupt (SIGINT) just terminates the program, without exiting with blocks and calling an __exit__() function.
With the try/except block, it calls __exit__() because it is catching the KeyboardInterrupt and exiting the with block which calls the __exit__() function. It probably won’t print a traceback, however...

I want to capture the keyboard interrupt and get that traceback, so this isn't ideal. Plus, this seems to be an mpi4py/MPI thing since running it with normal Python the __exit__ executes as expected.

Also, a try/except block does not capture the KeyboardInterrupt when run with mpirun, so even if I could wrap my code in a try/except it doesn't fix anything.

One, the traceback from a KeyboardInterrupt isn’t very helpful, and two, I would think that an alternate implementation of Python would still have core language elements, but anyway.

It's not so much the traceback that I need but the capture in __exit__ that it was a keyboard interrupt since my program does something different for keyboard interrupts than other exceptions.
